# How is a local variable in a closure a private member variable in Ext JS?

Tags: javascript, extjs, private-members

The tutorial at http://www.extjs-tutorial.com/extjs/declare-private-members-in-class-extjs provides an example of declaring private members in Ext JS classes. But I don't see how this is an example of private members.

Here is a code I have written that is very similar to the one in the link above. The only differences are that my code has the complete HTML to demo the JavaScript code and it has an extra statement that attempts to alert the supposedly private member variable named `name`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Ext-JS Private Problem</title>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/extjs/6.0.0/ext-all.js"></script>
<script>
Ext.define('Student', function(){
    var name = 'unnamed';

    return {
        constructor : function(name){
            this.name = name;
        },
        getName : function(){
            alert('Student name is ' + this.name);
        }
    };
});

//create an object of Student class
var studentObj = Ext.create('Student','XYZ');
studentObj.getName();
alert(studentObj.name);
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Both the alerts in this code succeed. In fact the final alert successfully displays `XYZ`.

In fact, I don't understand how the object vaiable `this.name` is even related to the local variable `name` of the closure? They are completely two different things.

How is the code in the tutorial a demonstration of a private variable then?

I thought perhaps the tutorial meant something like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Ext-JS Private Problem</title>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/extjs/6.0.0/ext-all.js"></script>
<script>
Ext.define('Student', function(){
    var name = 'unnamed';

    return {
        constructor : function(n){
            name = n;
        },
        getName : function(){
            alert('Student name is ' + name);
        }
    };
});

//create an object of Student class
var studentObjX = Ext.create('Student','XYZ');
var studentObjA = Ext.create('Student','ABC');
studentObjX.getName();
studentObjA.getName();
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

In this case, the variable `name` is indeed local to the closure but it doesn't behave like a *member variable* any more because both objects `studentObjX` and `studentObjA` share the same `name`. Both alerts display the same name, i.e. `ABC`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: It isn't.

The tutorial is plain wrong. There is no way one could implement private members in JavaScript objects, because hiding them is not supported by the language. They are always accessible - one way or another.

But then, the tutorial is neither written, reviewed nor approved by Sencha, the company that is developing, selling and supporting the framework.

Furthermore, there is no named author, no legal notice, and domain whois comes up blank.

Under these circumstances, you shouldn't trust any of the information on that page.

You can't even trust that the ExtJS docs are completely correct, let alone anonymous 3rd party "tutorials"...